# WPF refactor duplicate DataGridTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am setting up some of my datagrid columns to be wrappable and have a lot of duplicate code below. Im looking to extract this to a style and then perhaps define this at the DataGridTextColumn level but am not able to define the textbox, only the header. What I tried which is incomplete and does not allow me to find the column values to wrap:

```
    <Style x:Key="GridColumnWrap" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding Value}" />
    </Style>
```

Current XAML layout:

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Summary" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Summary}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Description" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resolution" Binding="{Binding Resolution}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the `DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WrapStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TestWrap" 
                            Binding="{Binding Path=TestValue}"
                            ElementStyle="{StaticResource WrapStyle}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: receive: `'WrapStyle' is not a valid value for property 'ElementStyle'`. Tried to change the TargetType to DataGridTextColumn and Style setting to `TextBlock.TextWrapping` but no luck..

Comment: @InContext: Strange, for me works fine. Can you give the full non working example?